# jquery add value to dynamically created input text field

Tags: jquery, input, dynamically-generated

I have a set of dynamically create input text boxes created via jQuery ajax and need to populate certain fields with values. I am using this;

```
$('#priority').attr('value', tplData);
```

but that does not seem to be working.

I tried .val(tplData), but to no avail.

Is there a different way to set the values of fields, via jQuery, that have been created dynamically?

The input field html is as follows;

```
<div class="field-container">
  <!-- This field is being dynamically created via an ajax call using jQuery -->
  <input type="text" name="priority" id="priority" class="input-group vert-spacer-bottom" placeholder="Priority">
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
It seems to definitely be something with dynamically create elements, because if I create the input element statically in the HTML and try these suggestions, it works perfect. But if the input fields are created dynamically, no dice.

Comment: are there multiple elements with the same id

Comment: No, they are all different. So, here's the weird part. I can make it work if I create the input element as a static HTML input field. Works like a charm. If I let jquery create it after the page is rendered though, can't get it to work at all regardless of implementation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after further banging of my head against the proverbial code wall, I was able to engineer a solution that ended up working superbly!

The dynamically created textbox is now accepting assignment of a value to it from my jquery code. The magic was in rethinking exactly how the element must be seen by jquery in terms of visibility to the code.

First thing to account for is that the container DIV is static and always present in the document. This means that anything created in that DIV will strictly be client-side always. Locking into a client-side frame of mind then led me to thinking that jQuery needs to be made aware of the newly created elements. This was achieved by the following code;

```
var inputElm = '';
inputElm += '<input type="' + data.type + '" name="' + data.name + '" id="' + data.name + '" class="' + data.name + ' input-group vert-spacer-bottom" placeholder="' + data.placeholder + '" />';

$('.field-container').after().html(inputElm);
```

Now, when I execute the code...it works beautifully and sets the value of the input textbox to the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('body').find('#priority').attr('value', tplData);
```

**EDIT** : It should be work, however you can do this too:

```
$('body').find('name=["priority"]').val(tplData);
$('body').find('#priority').val(tplData);
```

**EDIT:** See this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckczry6z/)

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work. Seemed a very reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Well, all of these look great, but none worked. Does it matter that I'm using the bootstrap library?

Comment: what's value of `tplData`? put your code completely here. I append `jsfiddle` link for your problem

Comment: It's derived from an AJAX call. It will typically be a 2 to 4 character string. e.g. "P1S2"  or "P2" ...etc.
Please go read my latest comment at the top also...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is,is your textbox generated before you assign the value to it.?? You can check if any error is there in console tab.Sometimes what happen if any error is occurred before your code it will not fire.So right click on page->Inspect Element->Console.If any errors then solve it and retry.

you can try like $('#priority').val(tplData)

Comment: Yes, the field is generated before attempt is made to push a value to it. Secondly, please see my OP as I already tried what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple controls then u have to use class

```
$(".priority").prop("value",tplData);
```

check if any errors in console.